# QO20303020 breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

Why do they make this breaker (20 30 30 20) if not for use as a Quad tandem breaker, two 240 volt 2 pole circuits, one 20 and one 30, in only two spaces? If not wouldn't it only be available as a 2 circuit, 20 30, single pole breaker by itself?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: 30A single-pole breakers have essentially no useful use, except for small RVs.

Answer (score 1):

Square D doesn't make much in the way of quadplex breakers for the QO line.

[image]

The [QO20303020](https://www.se.com/us/en/product/QO20303020/tandem-mini-circuit-breaker-qo-2-x-1-pole-at-20a-2-x-1-pole-at-30a-120-240vac-10ka-plug-in-mount/) appears to be a pair of tandem breakers - one with 30 on the left, the other with 30 on the right.

> for use as a Quad tandem breaker, two 240 volt 2 pole circuits, one 20 and one 30, in only two spaces?

No. Just because you need that doesn't mean Square D makes it.  You cannot use these for 120/240V circuits or feeders (i.e. ones with neutral) fullstop.

However, a *handle-tie* such as QOTHTCP can be used to tie adjacent 120V breakers.  This can be used for a 120V-only MWBC, or a 240V-only (no neutral) 240V circuit such as water heater, A/C or EV charging (provided it is hardwired or on a NEMA 6 socket; EVs don't actually use neutral but confusion reigns, and many run neutral anyway.)

So this is the secret here.  By selling you a pair with 30s on opposite sides, this permits you to handle-tie the 30's to power a 30A, 240V-only circuit. (A 30A, 120V MWBC is unlikely, since the only practical use for a 30A/120V circuit is small travel trailers.)

If you need a 240V 20A and a 240V 30A circuit each, you buy this breaker *and also* a QO2020 tandem, and two handle ties.  Build a stack that looks like

20/30--30/20--20/20

and stick the handle-ties at the "--" part.

Comment: OK so then they don't make a handle tie to tie the outboard 20s together, gotcha, thanks.

Comment: @Jim As far as I know, they do not, no. Those outer ones are pretty sketch even on the factory assembled quads.